# get all dates between multiple date range from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

This is **My MySQL table:**

```
Name      From          To           LeaveType
--------------------------------------------------
Ravi    2015-01-01    201-01-02      Casual Leave
Sudha   2015-01-02    201-01-02      Sick Leave
```

**Expected Output**

```
2015-01-01
-----------
1. ravi  CL

2015-01-02
-------------
1. ravi    CL
2. Sudha   SL
```

This is my **Mysql Query:**

```
SELECT 
      leave_id,
      emp_id,
      Employee_id,
      name,
      `from`,
      `to` 
FROM emp_leave    
WHERE hod_id='42' AND
      from` BETWEEN '2015-4-01' AND '2015-04-10' AND 
     `to` BETWEEN '2015-4-01' AND '2015-04-10' 
ORDER BY `from`
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Comment: `2015-4-01` is not a real date.

Comment: I am Not getting Excepted Output...

Comment: would you also expect it to interpolate? ie if it was from '2015-04-01' to '2015-04-03' would you expect it to show 2015-04-01, 2015-04-02 and 2015-04-03 ?

Comment: are you open to completely changing your table structure?

Comment: store every day they're away, rather than a range. it will make life a bit simpler

Comment: The `to` column contains `201-01-02` value, but the query is asking:  `to BETWEEN '2015-4-01' AND '2015-04-10' `, it's no a big surprise that the query doesn't find anything

Comment: You have a syntax error in your SQL statement, `from` is missing a backtick.  Be sure to paste your exact query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `to` dates have the wrong year.  You have `201-01-02` instead of `2015-01-02`.  Once that's fixed, and your query is changed to have the right dates and fix the syntax error, [it works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f28c2/1).

If it's still not working, it's possible that whatever `hod_id` is isn't `42`.

Be careful with your date formatting.  Many systems will accept single digit months like `2015-4-20`, but it is not [a proper ISO 8601 date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates).  The month should always have two digits, `2015-04-20`.